# Can't change the colour of my text with subscription

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am wanting to change the colour of my text with a service and subscription, however I cannot seem to get it to work properly?

I am using [ngClass] to dynamically set characters that are true for 'isActive', but I don't know why I cannot get this to work?

At present, only the first letter is being changed.
Also... I am hoping to change the colour of the highlighted letters changed by the [ngClass].

**[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/communicate-between-child-components)**

**html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="keys" *ngFor="let item of dataKeys">
    <div #text class="chars" *ngFor="let char of data[item]" [ngClass]="{'active': char.isActive}">
      {{char.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**component**

```
@ViewChild('text') private text: ElementRef;

  constructor(private service: SettingsService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscribeToColour();
  }

  subscribeToColour() {
    this.service.getColour.subscribe(res => {
      if (this.text) {
        this.text.nativeElement.style.color = res;
      }
    });
  }

  get dataKeys() {
    return Object.keys(this.data);
  }
```

**service**

```
export class SettingsService {
  default = 'green'
  colour = new BehaviorSubject<any>(this.default);

  setColour(colour) {
    this.colour.next(colour);
  }

  get getColour(): Observable<any> {
    return this.colour;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Peter said the view child reference you captured to "text" is only a reference to the first of the divs that you repeated.

As an alternative, you could consider adding the color to the data object:

Eg:
    {
        "name": "a",
        "isActive": true,
        "color": "red",
    }

And binding to this in your html file - you shouldn't really be manipulating the nativeElement property yourself

You would then update the property in your data object in your service subscriber as appropriate

Answer (score 0):

The `#text` is only pointing at the `div` for `a`. Therefore, `this.text.nativeElement.style.color = res;` only updates the color for `a`.

I modified your code a little bit:

`my-comp.component.html`

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="keys" *ngFor="let item of dataKeys">
    <div class="chars" *ngFor="let char of data[item]" [style.color]="char.isActive ? color : 'white'">
      {{char.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`my-comp.component.ts`

```
color: string = 'white';

subscribeToColour() {
   this.service.getColour.subscribe(res => {
     this.color = res;
   });
}
```

Note that I got rid of `#text` in your `html` file as well as the conditional block in your `ts` file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be setting the .isActive variable of any character in your code. That #text is not working how you want it to.

I think you may be overcomplicating this. You can simply change colors by setting them in your service without subscribing to a value.

Try something like:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="keys" *ngFor="let item of dataKeys">
    <div class="chars" *ngFor="let char of data[item]" [ngClass]="{'active': getColour(char.isActive)}">
      {{char.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




export class SettingsService {
  getColour(boolean): string {
    if (boolean == true) {
      return 'green'; // whatever colour you want.
    } else {
      return 'red' // whatever you want
    }
  }
```